# SMLNJ if statement error

Tags: if-statement, sml

I'm trying to learn SML and wrote a small game resembling the one in [Zed Shaw's book 'Learn Ruby The Hard Way'.](http://ruby.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex31.html) The code below works fine in the REPL and compiles well with MLTON. However, it always results in the else statement ("Error!"). If I try to debug it with `print(valOf(response))` in place of the if statements, it returns whatever string I type (an empty string if I don't type anything). So I don't think it is the inputLine function, it is also not that the let statement does not return the stdin, and it should also not be the comparison op.

```
fun first_room () =
    (print "You're in a dark, mottled room.\n";
     print "Which one do you choose? Left or Right?\n";
     print "> ";
     let val response = (TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn)
     in
     if response = NONE
     then print "You stay.\n"
     else if valOf(response) = "Left"
     then print "You go left.\n"
     else if valOf(response) = "Right"
     then print "You go right.\n"
     else print "Error!\n"
     end)

fun main () = first_room ()
         
val _ = main ()
```

So, I have two questions:
1 - What may cause this?
2 - Is this the ML (functional) way to build this procedural program?

## Following Sebastian's answer:

Just to inform casual reader:

Looking for ways to debug this error, I noticed that if I type `TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn;` in the REPL, and type some abc, I get "abc\n" back. I didn't knew that one can use the REPL for trying ML programs without compiling them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### What may cause this?

The value returned by `TextIO.inputLine` includes the trailing newline. That is, if you write `Left` and press enter, you actually get the string `"Left\n"` returned as the value.

To take care of this, you can make a simple trimming function, that you can use to remove that newline.

```
(* trimLast : string -> string
   Trims off the last character in a string *)
fun trimLast s = String.substring(s, 0, size s - 1)
```

#### Is this the ML (functional) way to build this procedural program?

Instead of writing a chain of `if`-expressions, it could be a lot cleaner if you made use of pattern matching, as well as separated out the handling of the `option` type returned by the `inputLine`. I would probably write it like this:

```
(* trimLast : string -> string
 * Trims off the last character in a string *)
    fun trimLast s = String.substring(s, 0, size s - 1)

fun processInput f =
    case TextIO.inputLine TextIO.stdIn of
        NONE   => print "Goodbye.\n"
      | SOME s => f (trimLast s)

(* empty room functions, to make the program compile *)
fun leftRoom () = ()
fun rightRoom () = ()

fun firstRoom () = (
    print "You're in a dark, mottled room.\n";
    print "Which one do you choose? Left or Right?\n";
    print "> ";
    processInput (fn
        "Left"   => ( print "You go left.\n"; leftRoom () )
      | "Right"  => ( print "You go right.\n"; rightRoom () )
      | _        => ( print "You do nothing.\n"; firstRoom () )
    )
  )
```

Notice how I've made the function `processInput`, which takes care of reading the input, and handling the option values. This also allows you to, for instance, normalize the input in one place, for instance if you wanted to lowercase it, to handle both `"Left"` and `"left"`.

Furthermore, I specify the rules for handling input as a function, which pattern matches on the string given.

I would consider this style more functional and clean.

Comment: At first it seemed to me like a string - option type error. I tried to debug this by printing, but failed to catch this one. What general rule should I follow during debugging to be able to detect such cause of errors? Do you have any suggestion for strong? ly typed languages?

Comment: Personally I tend to go through the program, verifying that the values are as I expect them at certain program points (by printing them, for instance), narrowing down where the problem occurs. :)